# Guardar checkbox seleccionados y no seleccionados

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una duda, quisiera saber si es posible guardar los checkbox que tengo de un detalle (tantos los seleccionados y los no seleccionados), por ejemplo, tengo un detalle de asistencia, donde me muestra todas las personas que están inscritas, y eso lo guardo en mi base de datos, pero mi pregunta va más allá, por que solo logro guardar los que he seleccionado y no puedo guardar lo que no seleccioné, a los seleccionados los ingreso un 1 y a los que no están con un 2.

Mi base guarda los siguientes campos:

- `id`: que es el id de mi asistencia.
- `alumno_id`: que es el id del alumno
- `asitencia`: 1:para quien esta, 2 para quien no seleccioné

Tengo en el detalle el input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="asistencia[]" id="asistencia[]" value="{{$al->id}}">
```

y mi código que guarda los datos

```
if($data=$request->asistencia){
        foreach ($data as $asis=>$valor){
            $asis= New AsistenciaAlumnos();
            $asis->alumno_id = $valor;
            if(isset($request->asistencia)) {
                $asis->asistencia = 1;
            }elseif(isset($request->asistencia)==NULL){
                $asis->asistencia = 2;
            }
            $asis->save();
        }
    }
```

Hasta aqui logro guardar los que he seleccionado, pero ¿Cómo puedo hacer para guardar los que no seleccioné?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Los checkboxes no seleccionados no se envían al backend.

Por ejemplo si seleccionas sólo uno o dos elementos, al presionar en `ver` te listará sólo los valores seleccionados:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  jQuery('#ver').on('click',function() {
    console.log(jQuery('#formulario').serializeArray());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario">
<input type="checkbox" id="pedro" name="pedro" value="1"><label for="pedro">pedro</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="juan" name="juan" value="1"><label for="juan">juan</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="diego" name="diego" value="1"><label for="diego">diego</label>
<input type="button" id="ver" value="ver valores">
</form>
```

La manera de abordar este comportamiento es **anteponer** un `input` de tipo `hidden` con el mismo `name` que el checkbox. Si el checkbox no está marcado, lo que recibe el backend es el valor del input hidden. Si está marcado, el valor del checkbox pisa al del input hidden dado que tienen el mismo nombre.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  jQuery('#ver').on('click',function() {
    console.log(jQuery('#formulario').serializeArray());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario">
<input type="hidden"  name="pedro" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="pedro" name="pedro" value="1"><label for="pedro">pedro</label>
<input type="hidden"  name="juan" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="juan" name="juan" value="1"><label for="juan">juan</label>
<input type="hidden"  name="diego" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="diego" name="diego" value="1"><label for="diego">diego</label>
<input type="button" id="ver" value="ver valores">
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amenadiel por tu respuesta, estoy implementado a mi código lo enviado, pero algo debo estar haciendo mal, porque en la consola me da el array vacio.

Comment: $("#ver").on('click',function() {
              console.log($(this).serializeArray() );
            });

Comment: Ah, pero `serializeArray` debe ejecutarse sobre un elemento `form`, no sobre el botón en sí. Yo puse el listener en el botón `#ver` pero serializo el contenido de `#formulario`. A lo mejor podrías poner el listener en el evento `submit` de tu formulario (y retornar false para que no te mande a la página de destino)

Comment: Perdón mi ignorancia, pero no es algo asi:  $("#ver").on('click',function() {
               console.log($('frm').serializeArray() );
            });

Comment: Si el formulario tiene id='frm' entonces sería `$('#frm')` en vez de `$('frm')`

Answer (score 1):

Quizas esto te pueda ayudar, en una variable podrías almacenar cada valor de los checbox y en otra el valor y el estado del checkbox (activo o no activo)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#btnGuardar").click(function() {
            var arrChk = new ArrayAsistencia();
            var arrGeneral = $('input[name="asistencia[]"]').map(function() {
            arrChk.push(this.value, this.checked);
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        console.log("Valor: " + arrGeneral);
        console.log("Valor y Estado: " + arrChk);
});
```

Y tu input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="asistencia[]" id="asistencia[]" value="{{$al->id}}">
```